# Identifying the content from the Web Browser using c#

Tags: c#, replace, webbrowser-control, substitution, mshtml

I created this with Web Browser Control in which only identify the specific word indicated in the codes. The only function of this is, it can read the content and highlight the words from the web page content. My only question is, how can i replace the string into another words (specifically change it into asterisk (*)) instead of highlighting it? Thank you.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(txbAdress.Text);
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder(doc2.body.outerHTML);

        var words = new[] { "bobo", "tanga", "gago" };
        foreach (String key in words)
        {
            String substitution = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);'>" + key + "</span>";
            html.Replace(key, substitution);
        }

        doc2.body.innerHTML = html.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> My only question is, how can i replace the string into another words
>   (specifically change it into asterisk (*)) instead of highlighting it?

Change:

```
String substitution = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);'>" + key + "</span>";
html.Replace(key, substitution);
```

to:

```
html.Replace(key, "*");
```

Or, if you're trying to blank out each specific character of the word with an asterisk, then build a string of asterisks as long as the length of `key` (which you can find out with the value of `key.Length`).

Comment: One more thing is, is it possible to count those words which is being replace by asterisk? and store it in the database or maybe create a report

Comment: @kyte use key.Length to get the length of the string. As for database/report, that would be best asked as a new question.